# Using javascript from python to set the value of a hidden input

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver

I'm converting an automated test case to use IE rather than FireFox. The case worked fine on Firefox, however I've found IE has a very strange behavior. It's duplicating the input for login credentials and hiding the input that I need to access. (Note this is IE doing it, not the source for the application I'm testing)

I'm using Selenium and Python, and I need to pass the login credentials to the hidden input fields. I'm aware that you cannot access hidden fields in Selenium, however I've seen a lot of SO posts saying you could do it with Javascript. Which brings me to my question. What am I doing wrong here? I'm not very familiar with Javascript, but everything I've seen so far indicates that this should work.

**My Python:** (Key is a parameter for the script)

`driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('form-control placeholder').setAttribute('value', '" + key + "')")`

[IE Page Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cTKF.png)

[IE Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdsH0.png)

Comment: can you try the below code. `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', arguments[1])",driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".form-control"),key)`

Comment: @SudharsanSelvaraj That resolved the error I encountered, though the application I'm testing still seems to be refusing the login attempt (valid credentials). Though that is beyond anything to do with this question. :)

Comment: Is there any specific error?

Comment: @SudharsanSelvaraj None that I can see. (IE's Debugger is terrible)
I know it accepts the credentials if they're typed manually, but inputting them via the script doesn't work in IE. (Only IE, tested previously with FireFox/Chrome and it worked fine) You can see the first input is entered properly, but the second input doesn't seem to be accepted.

Comment: Okay.Instead of `.setAttribute()` try using `arguments[0].value=arguments[1]`

Comment: @SudharsanSelvaraj It ran a bit slowly that time and I noticed it's actually inputting the second value into the first input field. So it's displacing the username and not providing a password. Which is why the application is failing the login. Also, could you put your original comment in an answer since that solved the scope of the original question?

Comment: so now can you able to login successfully?

Comment: No. As I mentioned previously, the Javascript is sending it to the wrong input field. It's replacing the username with the password instead of sending the input to the correct element.

Comment: Then the problem is with the locator you are using. Can you share the HTML code for username and password textboxes? and also the locators that you are using

Comment: I'm aware it is a locator issue. I do not currently have direct access to the source for the application, however I did provide a screenshot of the source as seen through IE.

Comment: For username use `driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='identity']")` and for password try `driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='password']")`

Comment: @SudharsanSelvaraj "input[type='password']" did the trick. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: Welcome:) if you find my answer is helpful then just accept it!!

Comment: I would, but you posted it as a comment, so I'm unable to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method getElementsByClassName returns an array so, you should try:

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('form-control placeholder')[0].setAttribute('value', '" + key + "')")
```

Comment: That does indeed solve the error, thank you. But I'd like to give Sudharsan credit for the answer since he provided a solution first. +rep though.